BC1 (Block Compression 1). When I convert my BC1 file into an image, I lose resolution
In BC1 I compress an image in a text file with 64 bits per line (each line representing a block of 4x4 pixels, so 16 pixels), 32 bits are pixels id in the color palette and 32 other bits are 2 colors in rgb565.
From this file that looks like that (the first line is here to identify if this is a BC1 file or not, and the second is the resolution of the image, here I have 11377, 11375 for all the 4x4 blocks and the 2 first lines)
BC1
364 500
0101010101010101010101010101010110111110111101111011101011110111
0000000000000000000000000000000000011000011000110001100001100011
0000000000000000000000000000000010111110111101111011111011110111
0000000000000000000000000000000010111110111101111011111011110111
0000000000000000000000000000000010111110111101111011111011110111
0000000000000000000000000000000010111110111101111011111011110111
...

From this I convert it into an image with this:
def decompression_1(txt):
    # Step 1: Analysis of compressed text
    compressed = txt.splitlines()
    if compressed.pop(0) == 'BC1':
        res = (compressed.pop(0)).split()
        res = ((int(res[0]), int(res[1]), 3))
        return res, compressed
    else:
        print("Le fichier n'est pas en BC1")

def decompression_2(res, compressed):
    # Step 2: Building the list of image blocks
    img_lst = []
    for i in compressed:
        color1 = (i[32:48])[::-1]
        color2 = (i[48:])[::-1]
        color = [[np.round(int(color1[0:5], 2)*255/31),
                  np.round(int(color1[5:11], 2)*255/63),
                  np.round(int(color1[11:16], 2)*255/31)],
                 [np.round(int(color2[0:5], 2)*255/31),
                  np.round(int(color2[5:11], 2)*255/63),
                  np.round(int(color2[11:16], 2)*255/31)]]
        palette = palette_fct(color[0], color[1])
        patch = (i[0:32])[::-1]
        patch_lst = []
        while len(patch) > 0:
            patch_lst.append(palette[int(patch[:2], 2)])
            patch = patch[2:]
        img_lst.append(patch_lst)
    return img_lst

def decompression_3(res, img_lst):
    # Step 3: Image reconstruction
    image_reconstituee = np.zeros(res)
    for i in range(0, res[0], 4):
        for j in range(0, res[1], 4):
            if img_lst:
                bloc = np.reshape((img_lst.pop(0)), (4, 4, 3))
                image_reconstituee[i:i+4, j:j+4] = bloc
    return image_reconstituee

def decompression_4(image_reconstituee):
    # Step 4: Converting the reconstructed image
    img_result = Image.fromarray(image_reconstituee.astype('uint8'))
    return img_result

It's split into multiple function so I can update the tkinter interface between each step.
The result looks like that
so each block of 4x4 px looks like just one big pixel. I think the error come from decompression_3 but I don't know.
I'm trying to have an image that has the same dimension. (It already does, but all pixels from a block have the same color, so it doesn't look like it is.)
